# Which archaeology-related questions are on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have already asked few questions on the border between archaeology and earth sciences, such as [this](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/564/101) or [this](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/118/101). I want to ask more, but I would like to be sure that they are on topic before asking.

What I would expect to be on topic, all the time or almost all the time:

- [archaeological geophysics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geophysical_survey_%28archaeology%29)
- stratigraphy (including archaeological approach, with [Harris Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harris-matrix) and like?)

Where I am not sure, and I would expect at least some (but not all) questions to be on topic:

- interactions between earth (including climate) and ancient people

  - archaeological dating of various events studied by paleo-(insert earth science here)
  - how climate changes influenced ancient people (and if and how ancient people influenced climate)
  - how did mining, agriculture and other past human activities influenced earth etc.
- ancient mining once again

  - what materials could people reach in certain time and space
  - their mining techniques
- flint knapping - techniques, how good are various rocks for knapping etc.

What I don't expect to be on-topic at all:

- any social and/or relegious aspects of archaeology (perhaps with exceptions of ways how people perceived and reflected earth and specific landmarks, i.e. cult of mountains in some cultures?)
- production of artifacts that is not directly tied to earth, geology, pedology etc.
- almost anything else

Answer (score 3):

Past, current and future human influence on climate is on topic.

Past, current and future human adaptation to climate conditions is a border case, which needs a case-by-case decision. As rule of thump questions, which are more about climate are on topic and those, which are more about humans are probably not on topic.

Comment: This concerns climate. Perhaps it could be extrapolated to other areas, but I would prefer the answers to concern other fields as well: especially (a) how people affected terrain and (b) using earth sciences (geology, geophysics etc.) to understand human past - the aim is to study how earth influences people, but the methodology is appropriate for earth sciences.